# Pass a value from controller one to controller two in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want the `custEmail` value from controller 1 to controller 2. I Tried everything but could not fetch data from there.

**Controller 1**

```
public function customerRegister(Request $req)
{
    $customer = new Customer;
    $customer->cust_name = $req->custName;
    $customer->cust_mob_no = $req->custNo;
    $customer->email = $req->custEmail;
    $customer->cust_addr = $req->custAddr;
    $customer->cust_type = $req->custType;

    $validatedData = $req->validate([
        'custName' => 'required',
        'custNo' => 'required|numeric',
        'custEmail' => 'required|email',
        'custAddr' => 'required',
        'custType' => 'required',
    ], [
        'custName.required' => 'Customer Name is required',
        'custNo.required' => 'Customer Whatsapp No is required',
        'custEmail.required' => 'Customer Email is required',
        'custAddr.required' => 'Customer Address is required',
        'custType.required' => 'Customer Type is required',
    ]);

    $customer->save();
    
    return redirect()->route('regSuc');
}
```

**Controller 2**

```
public function sendSuccessMail(Request $request)
{
    $details = [
        'title' => 'Mail From ETR Infotech',
        'body' => 'This is a Testing Email From Laravel'
    ];
    Mail::to("no-reply@etrinfotech.com")
        ->send(new RegisterSuccessMail($details));

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 
        'Customer Registration Successful!, We Will Get Back To You Soon.');
}
```

Comment: Create an instance of another controller & access the public method of the second controller. Pass any parameters from method one to method two. That's all.

Comment: You may also define routes from another controller method. And call the route. Moreover, you are free to pass any parameters using route calling.

Comment: @SAhmedNaim Can you help with the code

Comment: Don't call your `Controller 2` from `Controller 1`, that is inefficient and results in a superfluous request. Instead, extract the shared functionality into a service class and use [dependency injection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container) to provide the shared functionality to classes that require it. Alternatively, you could use [events](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events).

Comment: @SAhmedNaim never do that, it is not following SOLID principles and is unmaintainable...